# Autopost on facebook users wall

Tags: php

i have a task to automatically post from my site on users  wall they are logged in the same browser once giving all the permissions it should never ask again for giving permissions means   all the next post should be posted automatically on that users wall. can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Rquire a `stream_publish` permission (for example with redirect) and do a graph api call of type `post` to `/me/feed/` by PHP Facebook API.

After receiving permission you shuld exchange your access token to long-lived access token which will be fine for about 60 days.